# How to insert a Django template tag + HTML element in a HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

How can I safely add a piece of HTML with Django template tags in it using Javascript? For example, if I have something like this in my template:

```html
<div id="some-element">
  <span id="my-tag">{{ my_data }}</span>
</div>
<!-- rest of the html page -->
```

If I were to use a script to just edit the innerHTML of the div, like the script below, it'd would just read `{{ other-data }}` as a string. How can I make it become an actual Django template tag?

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("some-element").innerHTML = 
    `
    <h1>This is may new data {{ other-data }} </h1>
    {% if value %}
      <p>This is an if statement</p>
    {% endif %}
    `
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Django template* thing is not a client side thing, when a request comes to the server, Django renders the HTML file then responds with it, the HTML file gets manipulated on the *Server*

And you don't need Django to use conditionals, JS is already there to insert elements based on conditions.